# Given a HList how do you get a HMap

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have a `HList` of `Symbols`. I want to convert this into `HMap` with the `HList` values as the `keys` and the `value` mapping set to a generated object based on the `key`. The generated object holds state hence though default mapping can be known subsequent state is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... the thing is that Shapeless `HMap` is not as straight forward as `HList`, but the following can get you started

```
import shapeless._
import poly._

val hList = 'omg1 :: 'omg2 :: 'omg3 :: HNil

// lets assume that you want to map Symbols to kv-pairs String -> Int
// hence your HMap will have kv-pairs "omg1" -> 1, "omg2" -> 2...

class BiMapIS[K, V]
implicit val stringToInt = new BiMapIS[String, Int]

object myFoldPolyFunc extends Poly {
  implicit def caseSymbol = use(
    (hmap: HMap[BiMapIS], elem: Symbol) =>
      hmap + (elem.name -> elem.name.last.toString.toInt)
  )
}

val hMap = hList.foldLeft(HMap.empty[BiMapIS])(myFoldPolyFunc)

val v1 = hMap.get("omg1")
// Some(1)

val v2 = hMap.get("omg2")
// Some(2)
```

Answer (score -4):

Without further information and based on a very superficial knowledge about HList (my only perception is a List of `Tuple2`), I guess you could do that via iteration. A possible pseudo code would be:

```
// Presume tuple._1 is the key
val hmap = hlist.map{ tuple => (tuple._1, doSomething(tuple._1))}.toMap
```

Comment: unfortunately... your answer will not be helpful at all.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I'm not surprised given the vagueness and lack of the details of the question itself, and a very superficial knowledge I have for HList and HMap. But instead of pointing out how unhelpful my answer was, could you give more information on which part it's being unhelpful? So that others might be able to give more intelligent answer.

Comment: well... Shapeless HMaps and HList are quite different from Scala's List and Map. And in this particular case, your answer is more like giving a Python answer for a C++ question which will not hep the OP at all. And in my opinion you should remove this answer.